# Sorting error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid PG::UndefinedColumn in Rails/Grape app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

I want to sort all Campaign by `campaign_code` in my admin panel, to do so I've created code below in my endpoint and serializer which front will be have in response. The same logic works well for sorting by `id` or `name` but it wont worked for sorting of existing `campagin_code` number.

`endpoint`

```
optional :sort, type: Hash do
 optional :sort, type: Hash do
  optional :total, type: String, values: %w[asc desc]
 end
end

get do
  scoped_collection = scope_admin_resource(filter(Campaign.all))
  admin_serialize paginate(filter(sort(scoped_collection)))
end
```

`serializer`

```
class CampaignSerializer
  attributes :id, :total,

  attribute :total do |campaign|
    campaign.campaign_codes.count
  end
end
```

With that code I've an error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column campaigns.total does not exist

Answer (score 0):

There is no such column in campaigns table

Comment: I know that but I don't want to sort it by column table but by serialized parameters which are passed in response.